# Free heightmap (elevation?) dataset for Kraków, Poland?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, poland

Is there a freely available (governmental?) heightmap (=elevation?) dataset for Kraków city (in Poland) with horizontal grid ~5m (or better) and vertical resolution ~ +/- 0.1m? Ideally, it would *include* building heights (i.e. not "ground level").

If you don't know one, at least do you know of some good open forum where I could ask such a question with some hope of getting an answer?

*Sorry if that question doesn't use proper terms and/or is too unclear, or otherwise totally ridiculous; I'm totally unexperienced in GIS.*

Comment: Maybe ask on [(1) Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/ "(1) Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange"). You're probably looking for LIDAR data, which is sometimes available freely.

Comment: @scruss: done that already, someone there suggested that I ask here ;)

Comment: @scruss: hmmm, that seems to be a good direction: googling for LIDAR I found [some pdf article apparently using such data](http://yadda.icm.edu.pl/agro/element/bwmeta1.element.dl-catalog-cc129e17-2544-423d-91fb-70b15b3b6ef0/c/Borowiecki.pdf), which then seems to suggest Polish term "lotniczy skaning laserowy", which again leads to e.g. [some nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JLzQMqzyL0). Now what remains is to find out how to get access to this data.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, wow, wow, based on @scruss's hint, I maybe have found something; not exactly free, but really, really cheap (i.e. not "bussiness prices" but "average guy prices" apparently); only I must yet verify if the data is really good enough for me and what I think it is, but there are some samples. Without further ado, the links are:

http://codgik.gov.pl/index.php/zasob/numeryczne-dane-wysokosciowe.html - an overview of the available subtypes of data, and details on how to request them;

http://codgik.gov.pl/index.php/obsluga-klienta/oplaty-za-udostepnianie-materialow-fotogrametrycznych.html - pricing (seems 2-4zł per km<sup>2</sup> IIUC, which seems totally approachable).

*(Note: found based on information in [a GUGiK video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdmMReghqFk).)*